# Bitminter Blocks: why didn't my balance change?

Tags: mining-pools, balance, mining-pool-shares, pool-payout-methods

I recently started mining in BitMinter's Pool. I realized I had 10 proof of works accepted by the server, but my balance didn't change. What am I missing?

Comment: When you say "my balance", what do you mean?

Comment: When you say "proof of works accepted", what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

At Bitminter the work in the last 10 finished shifts get paid when a block is found.

If you only have work in the current unfinished shift at the time when the block is found, there is no payment.

If you only have work in old shifts (not the 10 latest ones) at the time when the block is found, there is no payment.

After you have done some work and the shift is finished, the work is eligible for pay until 10 more shifts are finished. It can take a full day for that to happen, and in the meantime you get paid for any blocks that are found. So it takes a while from you do the work until it is fully paid.